# Remove a group from scene

Tags: three.js, scene, removechild

I´m using Three.js, and I created a group of meshes  and inside  another group

```
pgrupo= new Array ();
fgrupo=new Array ();

scene.add(pgrupo[0])

pgrupo[0].add(fgrupo[0]):
pgrupo[0].add(fgrupo[1]):
```

How can I remove a fgroup from the scene?

if I use:

```
scene.remove(fgrupo[0]);
```

or

```
scene.remove(pgrupo[0]);
```

Nothing happened. How can I delete this things from the scene?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an Array use the [THREE.Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) and the .add() and .remove() methods.

So

```
pgrupo = new THREE.Object3D();
fgrupo = = new THREE.Object3D();

scene.add (pgrupo);
```

Also the method .children gives you an Array with object's children.