# How can I remove a group from a Three.js scene on click?

Tags: three.js

I have a group of objects (actually 3D text on an arc) that I want to remove from the scene on a specific click. Does .remove not work on groups? Here's basically what I have:

```js
$(".inscript").on("mousedown", function(event){    
  var x = scene.getObjectByName("inscriptArc");
  scene.remove(x);
});
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303578/remove-a-group-from-scene) seems to suggest you can (remove a group from a scene using .remove), but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Scene.getObjectByName` returns the first instance of a child with that name. If you have multiples you won't catch all of them by calling it once.

To remove all instances I would use the `THREE.Object.traverse(fn(child){})` function ie:

```js
var children_to_remove = [];
scene.traverse(function(child){
    if(child.name == "inscriptArc"){
       children_to_remove.push(child);
    }
});
children_to_remove.forEach(function(child){
    scene.remove(child);
});
```

You might be able to just do:

```js
scene.traverse(function(child){
    if(child.name == "inscriptArc"){
       scene.remove(child);
    }
});
```

but I think there are some cases where this could cause an error if you are loading/removing anything from the scene asyncronously - because removing a child might throw an error when that child's children get traversed. Not sure, so I would try the simple one and swap with the more complicated one if it causes issues.

Comment: ``children.length = 0 ``

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can remove a group of objects. You might have named children of the object instead of the actual group. Function `getObjectByName` did not always work as promised in older three.js releases so maybe try this.

```js
scene.children.forEach(child => child.name == "inscriptArc" ? scene.remove(child) : null)
```